# Possibility for further optimization of a "Bitmap Index Scan" on `inet` columns on a ~20M records table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I am working on optimizing a query on a simple table with ~21M records. The two main columns of the table are `node_ip_addr` and `nbr_ip_addr`, both of which are of type `inet`, which stores neighbors info data. So if A is neighbor of B, we can have the following 2 entries in the table:

```
A -> B
B -> A
```

Following is the tables DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_relation (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    node_ip_addr inet NULL,
    nbr_ip_addr inet NULL,
);
```

Indexes present on the table:

```
idx_tbl_relation_id                     CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_relation_id ON tbl_relation USING btree (id)
idx_tbl_relation_node_ip_addr_gist      CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_relation_node_ip_addr_gist ON tbl_relation USING gist (node_ip_addr inet_ops)
idx_tbl_relation_nbr_ip_addr_gist       CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_relation_nbr_ip_addr_gist ON tbl_relation USING gist (nbr_ip_addr inet_ops)
```

Note have already tried vacuum on the table:

```
vacuum analyze tbl_relation;
```

Following is the query that is to be optimized:

```
explain (analyze,buffers) SELECT * FROM  tbl_relation WHERE (node_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167' OR nbr_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167') AND (node_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185'   OR nbr_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185');
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on tbl_relation  (cost=459.24..463.26 rows=1 width=71) (actual time=142.336..142.336 rows=0 loops=1)
      Recheck Cond: (((node_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167'::inet) OR (nbr_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167'::inet)) AND ((node_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185'::inet) OR (nbr_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185'::inet)))
      Buffers: shared hit=13789
      ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=459.24..459.24 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=142.332..142.332 rows=0 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=13789
            ->  BitmapOr  (cost=33.05..33.05 rows=1095 width=0) (actual time=70.667..70.667 rows=0 loops=1)
                  Buffers: shared hit=6894
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_relation_node_ip_addr_gist  (cost=0.00..11.30 rows=385 width=0) (actual time=44.895..44.895 rows=10 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (node_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167'::inet)
                        Buffers: shared hit=4256
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_relation_nbr_ip_addr_gist  (cost=0.00..21.74 rows=710 width=0) (actual time=25.767..25.767 rows=3 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (nbr_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167'::inet)
                        Buffers: shared hit=2638
            ->  BitmapOr  (cost=425.94..425.94 rows=16147 width=0) (actual time=71.651..71.651 rows=0 loops=1)
                  Buffers: shared hit=6895
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_relation_node_ip_addr_gist  (cost=0.00..404.19 rows=15437 width=0) (actual time=45.983..45.983 rows=15831 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (node_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185'::inet)
                        Buffers: shared hit=4262
                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_tbl_relation_nbr_ip_addr_gist  (cost=0.00..21.74 rows=710 width=0) (actual time=25.662..25.662 rows=0 loops=1)
                        Index Cond: (nbr_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185'::inet)
                        Buffers: shared hit=2633
    Planning Time: 0.159 ms
    Execution Time: 142.461 ms
```

Some info about the data:

```
select count(*) from tbl_relation;
-- 21,058,705
```

```
select nbr_ip_addr , count(*) from tbl_relation group by nbr_ip_addr order by count(*) desc;
10.81.255.11    76788
10.72.0.202     50299
10.72.9.75      40949
10.72.65.150    38533
10.64.1.176     37262
10.72.65.146    33601
10.72.73.40     33566
.
.
.
```

```
select node_ip_addr , count(*) from tbl_relation group by node_ip_addr order by count(*) desc;
10.72.9.75      39310
10.72.0.202     34655
10.81.255.11    25730
10.64.1.176     18443
10.109.64.25    17206
10.72.65.150    16006
10.14.9.185     15831
.
.
.
.
```

Its an 8 core, 32GB RAM machine, all of which available to postgres.

Postgres version:

```
PostgreSQL 11.6 (Ubuntu 11.6-1.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
```

Following are the postgres settings:

```
maintenance_work_mem        65536   kB
work_mem                    409600  kB
shared_buffers              393216  8kB
commit_delay                100000
max_wal_size                10240   MB
min_wal_size                1024    MB
effective_io_concurrency    8
```

```
select pg_size_pretty (pg_relation_size('tbl_relation'));
-- 1834 MB
```

With the given size of table and the config, is this the best we can get? Are there any other index combination we can try? Any settings in postgres?
Or any other way of querying?
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: 0.142 seconds is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff this query is called multiple times per second and the cumulative time is high.

Comment: 1) you don't need the surrogate key `id` 2) There should be an UNIQUE constraint on `(node_ip_addr, nbr_ip_addr)` and one on `(nbr_ip_addr, node_ip_addr)` (this could be only a unique index)

Comment: BTW: your AND/OR logic seems rather non-standard. Have you tried `x IN(a,b) AND y IN (a,b)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT version();

CREATE TABLE tbl_relation (
    node_ip_addr inet NOT NULL  -- <<-- NOT NULL
    , nbr_ip_addr inet NOT NULL -- <<-- (NULL keyvalues in a junction table make no sense)
        , PRIMARY KEY( node_ip_addr, nbr_ip_addr)       -- <<-- will imply an index 
        , UNIQUE (nbr_ip_addr, node_ip_addr)            -- <<-- will imply an index 
);

ANALYZE tbl_relation;

EXPLAIN
SELECT * FROM tbl_relation
WHERE node_ip_addr IN ('10.14.221.167' , '10.14.9.185')
AND nbr_ip_addr IN ('10.14.221.167' , '10.14.9.185')
        ;
```

---

Result: (no data, but the single index scan would probably remain)

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
                                                 version                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.6 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0, 32-bit
(1 row)

CREATE TABLE
ANALYZE
                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using tbl_relation_nbr_ip_addr_node_ip_addr_key on tbl_relation  (cost=0.15..2.85 rows=1 width=64)
   Index Cond: ((nbr_ip_addr = ANY ('{10.14.221.167,10.14.9.185}'::inet[])) AND (node_ip_addr = ANY ('{10.14.221.167,10.14.9.185}'::inet[])))
(2 rows)
```

---

**Extra**: you *could* try to further optimise using `CLUSTER`, which will keep the records more or less sorted, but that would need periodic maintenance (reclustering), especially if the table contents change often:

```
CLUSTER tbl_relation USING tbl_relation_pkey;
-- Or:
-- CLUSTER tbl_relation USING tbl_relation_nbr_ip_addr_node_ip_addr_key;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try this approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_relation r
WHERE node_ip_addr = '10.14.221.167'::inet AND nbr_ip_addr IN ('10.14.221.167'::inet, '10.14.9.185'::inet)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM tbl_relation r
WHERE node_ip_addr = '10.14.9.185'::inet AND nbr_ip_addr IN ('10.14.221.167'::inet, '10.14.9.185'::inet)
```

I would then try a standard index on `tbl_relation(node_ip_addr, nbr_ip_addr)`.

Postgres does not (yet) support a "skip-scan" for the index.  This should turn into two direct index lookups.  If this meets your requirements for performance, there might be alternative ways to get a similar plan.